# texreg output with RStudio and rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, texreg

I have a question that seems so simple and fundamental that I can't find the solution online.  How do I make knitr (or Pandoc) evaluate the output given by the texreg functions?

### A minimal example:

My entire .rmd file code:

````
---
title: "test texreg"
output: pdf_document
date: "January 27, 2016"
---

```{r}
library(texreg)
texreg(list(lm(speed~dist,data=cars)))
```
````

When I click Knit PDF (or Knit HTML or Knit Word) I get LaTeX code for the table but each line starts with two pound symbols, i.e. the r output from the `texreg()` function as if I had run it at the console.  I have the same issue if I use `htmlreg()`

I assume that I just have to put the function call somewhere else?  I can't seem to figure it out...

This question ([R markdown "texreg"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779143/r-markdown-texreg?rq=1)) seems to ask the exact same question but the answer is unhelpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the most elegant solution to my problem but I did discover *a* solution:  Put the call to `texreg()` into an inline r block like so:

````
```{r}
library(texreg)
```

`r texreg(list(lm(speed~dist,data=cars)))`
````

This produces the LaTeX output in such a way that Pandoc and now identify it an produce the LaTeX table.

I would be happy to accept more informed answers if they come along.

#### Edit:

Another option: add  `results="asis"` to the code chunk header.  I tried that originally but another error prevented me from seeing the correctly formatted table and consequently I didn't realize I had stumbled upon the solution.